# Strapi: use different urls for media upload and download

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, strapi

I have the following situation:

i'm writing a microservice that processes images uploaded to many different s3 buckets (it's a serverless function). It processes the original image saved in a `tmp/path/to/image.png` folder and stores the processed version in `path/to/image.png` (same bucket, same key, no prefix).

THE ISSUE:

Some of the applications that will use the microservice are **Strapi** applications for which I would need to specify a way to tell strapi (a pretty closed system) to put images in one place and get them from somewhere else.

I am not a Strapi expert by any means and I can't seem to find any way to do this. I'm trying a lifecycle hook, but i'm not being able to access the file from there... does anyone have a possible solution? I don't mind if it's a bit hacky.

Thanks a lot in advance!